# how to get a value of a progress bar in kivymd inside its class

Tags: error-handling, kivy, attributeerror, kivymd

**.PY FILE**

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
KV='''
<LoadingScreen>:
    name:'loading'
    MDScreen:
        MDFloatLayout:
            FitImage:
                source:'background_img.jpg'
            MDLabel:
                text:'WELCOME TO'
                font_style:'Subtitle1'
                bold:True
                pos_hint:{'center_x':.5,'center_y':.9}
                color:0,0,0,1
                size_hint_y: None
                halign:'center'
            MDLabel:
                text:'Health CheckUp App'
                bold:True
                name_theme:'Primary'
                underline:True
                font_style:'H5'
                font_name:'Sylfaen'
                pos_hint:{'center_x':.5,'center_y':.8}
                color:0,0,0,1
                size_hint_y: None
                halign:'center'
            MDLabel:
                text:'--prevention is better than cure'
                font_style:'Subtitle1'
                name_theme:'Secondary'
            
            MDProgressBar:
                id: progress_bar1
                pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.25}
                size_hint_x: 0.8
                    
            MDSeparator:
            MDLabel:
                text:'Loading...'
                font_style:'Caption'
                font_name:'Comic'
                bold:True
                pos_hint:{'center_x':.5,'center_y':.1}
                color:0,0,0,1
                size_hint_y: None
                halign:'center'
<HomeScreen>:
    name: "home_screen"
    MDScreen:
        FitImage:
            source: 'background_img.jpg'
        MDLabel:
            text:'Hello! '
            font_style:'H5'
            size_hint_y:None
            color:0,0,0,1
            bold:True
            height:self.texture_size[1]
            halign:'center'
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .7}
<RootWidget>:
    LoadingScreen:
        name:'loading'
    HomeScreen:
        name: "home_screen"
'''
class LoadingScreen(Screen):
    def on_enter(self, *args):
        self.progress = 0
#doubt  self.progress_bar = self.progress_bar1.value#self.root.get_screen('loading').ids.progress_bar
        self.progress_bar.max = 100
        self.progress_bar.value = 0
        self.loading_event = Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_progress, 0.02)

    def update_progress(self, dt):
        self.progress += 1
        self.progress_bar.value = self.progress
        if self.progress >= 100:
            self.loading_event.cancel()
            self.manager.current = 'home_screen'
class HomeScreen(Screen):
    pass
class RootWidget(ScreenManager):
    pass
class MainApp(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.data_tables = None
    self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Purple"
        self.theme_cls.primary_hue = "700"
        return RootWidget()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

This is the code.
***Here, I am getting this error when I run this code.
`Attribute error : 'LoadingScreen' object has no attribute 'progress_bar1'`***

HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE.

---

--self.root.get_screen('loading').ids.progress_bar
*if I use the above code and try running, it says that root is available inside Screen class. PLease tell what is the code that should be written instead on that.*
Expecting a page with progress bar loading and when it is fully loaded it should redirect to next page.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `on_enter` is executed before the `LoadingScreen` is completely prepared, so the `ids` in the `LoadingScreen` is empty. The fix is to delay accessing the details of `LoadingScreen` by using `Clock.schedule_once()`. Some thing like this:

```
class LoadingScreen(Screen):

    def on_enter(self, *args):
        Clock.schedule_once(self.setup_progressbar)

    def setup_progressbar(self, dt):
        self.progress = 0
        self.progress_bar = self.ids.progress_bar1
        self.progress_bar.max = 100
        self.progress_bar.value = 0
        self.loading_event = Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_progress, 0.02)
```